# Why is my for loop overwriting instead of appending CSV?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-datareader

I am trying to scrape IB website. So, what I am doing, I have created the urls to iterate over, and I am able to extract the required information, but seems the dataframe keeps being overwritten vs appending.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame as df
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import requests

base_url = "https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/index.phpf=2222&exch=mexi&showcategories=STK&p=&cc=&limit=100"
n = 1

url_list = []

while n <= 2:
    url = (base_url + "&page=%d" % n)
    url_list.append(url)
    n = n+1

def parse_websites(url_list):
    for url in url_list:
        html_string = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_string.text, 'lxml') # Parse the HTML as a string
        table = soup.find('div',{'class':'table-responsive no-margin'}) #Grab the first table
        df = pd.DataFrame(columns=range(0,4), index = [0]) # I know the size 

        for row_marker, row in enumerate(table.find_all('tr')):
            column_marker = 0
            columns = row.find_all('td')
            try:
                df.loc[row_marker] = [column.get_text() for column in columns]
            except ValueError:
            # It's a safe way when [column.get_text() for column in columns] is empty list.
                continue

        print(df)
        df.to_csv('path_to_file\\test1.csv')

parse_websites(url_list)
```

Can you please take a look at my code at advise what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Don't you want to be creating a dataframe once outside the loop, appending to the dataframe from inside your `for url in...` and then writing it once outside the loop?

Comment: I s'pose you could just cheat though and use: `df.to_csv('path_to_file\\test1.csv', mode='a')` but you'd need to make sure to exclude headers... else you'll get it for every iteration of the loop.

Comment: @JonClements , You sir , are a genious !!! Worked like a charm. Was going crazy with this one. Thanks much !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define a data structure from within a loop, each iteration of the loop 
will redefine the data structure, meaning that the work is being rewritten.

The dataframe should be defined outside of the loop if you do not want it to be overwritten.

Answer (score 3):

One solution if you want to append the data frames on the file is to write in append mode:

```
df.to_csv('path_to_file\\test1.csv', mode='a', header=False)
```

otherwise you should create the data frame outside as mentioned in the comments.